# Community Guest User cannot see records created by Customer Community users

Tags: community, guest-user

I have a Guest sharing rule that allows the Guest user to see records created by internal Salesforce users.  However, the Guest user isn't able to see records created by Customer Community users.

Answer (score 0):

My Guest user couldn't see records created by Customer Community portal users because this is a limitation of that license type.  I modified my code to work around this limitation.